Unable to start Cassandra after 3.11 to 4.1 upgrade
I'm trying to upgrade test cassandra cluster from 3.11.17 to 4.1.5, I wanted to do in rolling fashion so upgrade was done on the first node but the node is not is not starting up with the below error. Can you please let me know what is the issue here
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-21] 2024-07-30 04:46:26,203 NoSpamLogger.java:105 - /host1:7000->/host2:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-[no-channel] failed to connect
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: /host2:7000
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124)
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:673)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:530)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

host1 - Is the IP address of the node where upgrade was done
host2 - is the existing node in cluster with previous version
Thanks

The log message you posted indicates that host1 is unable to gossip with host2 (port 7000 is the default for node-to-node messaging). However it is logged at INFO which means that it is not necessarily the reason why Cassandra won't start on the upgraded node.
You will need to review the logs and specifically look for entries at ERROR level as those will give you clues as to why it won't start. Cheers!

Thanks, configuration parameter change helped the node to startup. The node with new cassandra version(4.1) , looks good meaning nodetool and cqlsh commands works as expected but I could see that other nodes in cluster (with version 3.11) show the node which was upgraded as DN in nodetool status. Probably the old 3.11 version nodes are not able to communicate with 4.1 node, what might be the issue here ? How can I fix this ?
